# Confused about single quotes/double quotes and \\ with respect to split

Tags: perl

So, I saw in another post that to split using `\\` as a delimiter, you need to split on `\\\\\\\\`.  This didn't really make sense to me, but when I attempted to split using `\\\\`, this happened:

```
my $string="a\\\\b\\\\c";
my @ra=split("\\\\",$string);
```

Array is:

```
a
<empty>    
b
<empty>
c
```

As the other poster said, using `\\\\\\\\` works perfectly.  Why is this the case?

Also, I got curious and started messing with `''` vs `""` and got unexpected results.  I thought that I understood what the difference is, but I guess I didn't, at least not in the following context:

```
my $string="a\.\.b\.\.c";
my @ra=split("\.\.",$string);
```

Array is:

```
<empty>
<empty>
<empty>
c
```

Yet,

```
my $string="a\.\.b\.\.c";
my @ra=split('\.\.',$string);
```

Array is:

```
a
b
c
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, quoting rules and regexes.

#### Backslash rules with different quotes

- In `q()` and related, all backslashes are left in the string, unless they escape the string delimiter or another backslash:

  ```
  say '\a\\b\''; # »\a\b'«
  ```
- In `qq()` and related, all backslashes that do not form a known string escape sequence are silently removed:

  ```
  say "\d\\b\"\."; # »d\b."«
  ```
- Ditto in `qr//` and regex literals, except that there are different escapes compared to double quoted strings.

If a string is used in place of a regex, then during compilation the escape rules for that kind of string are performed. However, a second level of escapes is processed when it is used as a regex, hence backslashes have to be double-escaped in the worst cases. Regex literals don't suffer from this problem; there is only one level of escaping.

#### Explanations for your examples

Therefore, `"a\\\\b\\\\c";` is `a\\b\\c`, and `"\\\\"` is `\\` which matches `\` as a regex. So it splits on every backslash, thus producing zero-length fields in between the double backslashes.

The `'\\\\\\\\'` of the other question you meant is `\\\\` which as a regex matches `\\`.

The `"a\.\.b\.\.c"` is `a..b..c`, and `"\.\."` is `..` which as a regex matches two non-newline characters. It first matches `a.`, then `.b`, then `..`. This produces the string fragments `"", "", "", "c"`.

The string `'\.\.'` is `\.\.`, which as a regex matches two literal periods in sequence.

The solution is to use regexes where regexes are due. `split` takes a regex as first argument like `split /foo/`, in other scenarios the regex quote `qr/foo/` is useful. This avoids mind-bending<sup>[1]</sup> double escaping.

<sub>[1]: for small values of  ”mind bending”, once you grok the rules.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

- In single-quoted strings literals,

  - `\` followed by the string delimiter (`'` by default) results in the string delimiter.

    ```
    'That\'s fool\'s gold!'   -> That's fool's gold!
    q!That's fool's gold\!!   -> That's fool's gold!
    ```
  - `\` followed by `\` results in `\`.

    ```
    'c:\\foo'                 -> c:\foo
    ```
  - `\` followed by anything else results in those two characters.

    ```
    'c:\foo'                  -> c:\foo
    ```
- In double-quoted strings literals,

  - `\` followed by non-word character results in that character.

    ```
    "c:\\foo"                 -> c:\foo
    "Can't open \"foo\""      -> Can't open "foo"
    ```
  - `\` followed by word character has a special meaning.

    ```
    "foo\n"                   -> foo{newline}
    ```
- In regular expressions literals,

  - `\` followed by the delimiter is replaced results in the delimiter.

    ```
    qr/\//                    -> /
    ```
  - `\` followed by anything else results in those two characters.

    ```
    qr/\\/                    -> \\
    qr/\_/                    -> \_
    qr/\$/                    -> \$
    qr/\n/                    -> \n
    ```
- When applying a regular expressions,

  - `\` followed by non-word character matches that character.

    ```
    /c:\\foo/                 -> Matches strings containing: c:\foo
    ```
  - `\` followed by word character has a special meaning.

    ```
    /foo\z/                   -> Matches strings ending with: foo
    ```

---

Looking at your cases:

```
 my $string="a\\\\b\\\\c";
 my @ra=split("\\\\",$string);
```

`"\\\\"` results in the string `\\`, so you first create the string `a\\b\\c` and you pass `\\` to `split`.

The first argument of `split` is used as a regular expression, and the regex pattern `\\` matches a single `\`. There are 4 `\` in `a\\b\\c`, so it gets split into 4+1 pieces.

If you use regex literals instead of double-quoted string literals, there will be less confusion.

```
split(/\\/, $string);        # Passes pattern \\ to split. Matches singles
split("\\\\", $string);      # Passes pattern \\ to split. Matches singles
split(/\\\\/, $string);      # Passes pattern \\\\ to split. Matches doubles
split("\\\\\\\\", $string);  # Passes pattern \\\\ to split. Matches doubles
```

In short, don't use `split "..."`!

---

Your other two cases should be obvious to you by now.

```
my $string="a\.\.b\.\.c";          # String a..b..c
my @ra=split("\.\.",$string);      # Pattern .., which matches any two chars.

my $string="a\.\.b\.\.c";          # String a..b..c
my @ra=split('\.\.',$string);      # Pattern \.\., which matches two periods.
```

Answer (score 0):

Split using /\\\\/ instead of "\\\\" and avoid all the worries,

e.g.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $string= "a\\\\b\\\\c";

my @ra = split /\\\\/, $string;

print Dumper @ra;
```

will output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c'
        ];
```

/\\/  will match a two \ in a row

or you can be cute and do

```
split /\\{2}/, $string
```

Comment: I understood how to do it with regexs, but I wanted to know what exactly was happening when I was using `''` and `""`.  Ikegami and Amon explained it very well.  Thanks for the reply anyway.