# Perl, dynamically generated regexp string with backslashed metacharacters strange behaviour

Tags: regex, perl

Here is small perl snippet:

```
my $n = 1;
my $re_str = '\d';
my $re_str_q = '\Q1\E';

printf "re_str   match: %s\n", ($n =~ /$re_str/);
printf "re_str_q match: %s\n", ($n =~ /$re_str_q/);
printf "direct match: %s\n", ($n =~ /\Q1\E/);
```

When run produces following output:

```
re_str   match: 1
re_str_q match: 
direct match: 1
```

So, my question here is why the second `printf` doesn't match ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The \Q isn't a regex escape, it's a string escape that is substituted in the string, so "\Q1\E" would be equivalent to quotemeta('1').

So you need to either use a quote that can interpolate those sequences, like "" or qr//, or call quotemeta instead of trying to use the string escape.

Answer (score 9):

If you change

```
my $re_str_q = '\Q1\E'; #from 
my $re_str_q = qr/\Q1\E/; #to
```

which would be the correct way to pass a dynamically generated regex, then it would give the following result

```
re_str   match: 1
re_str_q match: 1
direct match: 1
```

Also if you had used

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

you would get a warning

```
Unrecognized escape \Q passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\Q <-- HERE 1\E/ at so.pl line 9.
Unrecognized escape \E passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\Q1\E <-- HERE / at so.pl line 9.
```

Which would have given you some indication as to what was going wrong.

**UPDATE**

To understand this in further detail, you can read from **[here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)**

*The take away from the referenced document*

The following escape sequences are available in constructs that **`interpolate`**, but not in **`transliterations`**.

```
\l  lowercase next character only
\u  titlecase (not uppercase!) next character only
\L  lowercase all characters till \E or end of string
\U  uppercase all characters till \E or end of string
\F  foldcase all characters till \E or end of string
\Q quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till \E or
end of string
\E  end either case modification or quoted section
(whichever was last seen)
```

See [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for the exact definition of characters that are quoted by \Q .

\L , \U , \F , and \Q can stack, in which case you need one \E for each. For example:

```
say"This \Qquoting \ubusiness \Uhere isn't quite\E done yet,\E is it?";
This quoting\ Business\ HERE\ ISN\'T\ QUITE\ done\ yet\, is it?
```

Comment: @TLP, Made a document reference, which would explain it in further detail.

Answer (score 3):

You are using single quotes to build-up your "dynamically generated regexp". With `use warnings` perl will tell you:

> Unrecognized escape \Q passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\Q <-- HERE 1\E/ at ...

`perldoc perlop` will tell you:

> Single Quotes
>
> Single quotes indicate the text is to be treated literally with no interpolation of its
>    content. This is similar to single quoted strings except that backslashes have no special
>    meaning, with "\\" being treated as two backslashes and not one as they would in every other
>    quoting construct.
>
> This is the only form of quoting in perl where there is no need to worry about escaping
>    content, something that code generators can and do make good use of.

Answer (score 2):

\Q and \E are both handled by string interpolation, not the regex engine.  You bypass string interpolation in the first and second `printf` lines.  Search *Programming Perl* for "seven translation escapes" to get a discussion of this.  They are: `\N{...} \U \u \L \l \E \Q \F`. (Don't ask me why there are eight of them.)

Comment: +1 for explaining `\d` vs `\Q`, which seemed to be puzzling the OP

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of escapes involved with regular expressions.

- Escapes that are processed when parsing the literal.
- Escapes that are processed by the regex engine.

For example,

- `\Q..\E` is the former kind.
- `\d` is the latter kind.
- `\n` is both kind.

That means that

- `"abc\Q!@#\Edef"` produces the 12 char string `abc\!\@\#def`.
- `qq/abc\Q!@#\Edef/` is exactly the same thing.
- `qr/abc\Q!@#\Edef/` produces the 12 char string `abc\!\@\#def`, then it compiles it as a regex pattern that matches the 9 chars `abc!@#def`.

But single-quotes don't process such escapes, so

- `'abc\Q!@#\Edef'` produces the 13 char string `abc\Q!@#\Edef`.

The regex engine doesn't understand `\Q` or `\E`, so it'll give warnings if you end up passing the last string to it, then it'll try to match the 11 chars `abcQ!@#Edef`.

The fix is to change

```
my $re_str   = '\d';         # Produces string \d
my $re_str_q = '\Q1\E\';     # Produces string \Q1\E
```

to

```
my $re_str   = "\\d";        # Produces string \d
my $re_str_q = "\Q1\E";      # Produces string \1
```

or better yet,

```
my $re_str   = qr/\d/;       # Produces regex \d
my $re_str_q = qr/\Q1\E/;    # Produces regex \1
```

---

[Read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16576952/589924) for more on `\` specifically.